# selecting multiple lines grouping by 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have the following table on the DB :

[table MESSAGE_ZBUS_ORAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r02IX.jpg)

and i need to perform a selection with the following conditions :

Optimum traite les messages par ordre de 1 à 9
Pour un même ordre et pour un id ORAS différent, Optimum doit traiter par ordre croissant en fonction de la date d'envoi dans la stream ZBUS
Pour un même ordre et pour un id ORAS identique, Optimum doit traiter le dernier message en fonction de la date d'envoi dans la stream ZBUS (le plus récent).

- we select all the data sorted by ordre from 1 to 9
- if "ORDRE" is the same :

  - if "ID_ADR_ORAS_CONCERNE" is the same : we take the most recent line (only one line), based
    on SENT_DATE
  - if "ID_ADR_ORAS_CONCERNE" is different : we take both of them, sorted by SENT_DATE

for now this is what I did :

```
SELECT m.ORDRE , MAX(m.SENT_DATE) , m.ID_ADR_ORAS_CONCERNE, m.*
FROM OPTIMUM.MESSAGE_ZBUS_ORAS m
GROUP BY m.ORDRE , m.ID_ADR_ORAS_CONCERNE
```

but I can't select all columns ?
can you help please ?

Comment: A [mcve] would make everything clearer, to all of us.

Comment: If `sent_date` is *unique* you could simply `SELECT MAX(SENT_DATE) FROM ...` and `JOIN` the result `ON` the table itself, if unique for `ordre` and `oras` you could select all three and include them in the join.

Comment: @Aconcagua the sent date is not unique, and we can't take just the max(sent-date) because if the "order" is the same and the "id_adr_oras_concerne" is different, we should select everything with a sort on the date.
And for the joint, I tried it but I can't select the ID in the inner select to join ON after

Comment: Wait, `id_oras` is different from `id_adr_oras_concerne`??? As there yet appears `oras` I assumed all of these refer to the same. Not the case?

Comment: @Aconcagua not at all, i will correct it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.